# Use Grep to extract just email addresses from text file list of email addresses with names

Tags: text, grep, textwrangler

this is a similar question to some that are already out there, but couldn't find one that answered my question specifically, so thank you for any assistance/insight.

So I have a text file that I've opened in TextWrangler (popular Mac text editor) with email names and addresses. sample records:

```
Timmy Turner <tturner@example.com>
"jamminjeff@example.com" <jamminjeff@example.com>
Susan Alder <suesblues@example.com>,
sallyartist@example.com
```

So some email addresses with names preceding them, most emails enclosed by <> brackets, and some emails just by themselves, already correct, and some with commas after. I want to do a global process that will automate the process of getting this end result, either via Grep or something similar:

```
tturner@example.com
jamminjeff@example.com
suesblues@example.com
sallyartist@example.com
```

Thanks for any insight!

Answer (score 1):

sed might work better.   You can use a regex to remove the patterns that you don't want:

```
sed -e "s|.*<||" -e "s|>.*||"  your_file.txt  > new_file.txt
```

Comment: Thanks, user! Sorry, as I'm not very knowledgeable on this stuff, what is sed, and regex for that matter? Can I do a "sed" or a "regex" in a simple text editor?

Comment: The regular expressions are .*<  and >.*   The .* means match any character.  So it's stripping off anything before < or after >.  sed is a command line utility.  You'll find it in the mac terminal shell.  Though textwrangler should support regex in find/replace too, I thought.

Comment: Thanks, user. OK, so if I don't want to create a new file, do I just put part of that expression in the "find" window, and part of it into the "replace" window? Will that change the file line by line and just leave me with the email addresses? I already have the original file saved elsewhere. Thanks for any further insight!

Comment: So User, check it out, I took the first part of your solution:

    s|.*<||

And I entered that into the "Find" window, then I ran a "replace all," and it took away EVERYTHING from each line except the email address, even the '>' after the email! Don't know why, but that did it. Thank you!

Comment: So actually, I was a bit wrong. First, I had already removed the trailing ">" with a simple search and replace, so I had already done that, forgot. :) But then, when I replaced s|.*<|| with nothing, it not only removed everything that came before the email address, but it  also removed every "s" in every email address. I tried removing the "s" and just replacing |.*<|| with nothing, but that caused no result. Thanks for any additional insight.

Comment: OK, figured it out. First ran -e "s|.*<||" with the -e and the quotes, and that took away the stuff in front of the email address. Then I ran -e "s|>.*||" and that removed everything after the email addresses. So now I have just the email addresses. Thanks for your insight!!

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR**

Search:

```
^.*<?\b([a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*|"(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21\x23-\x5b\x5d-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])*")@((?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?|\[(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]:(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21-\x5a\x53-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])+)\])\b>?.*$
```

Replace:

```
\1@\2
```

**Explanation:**

According to [this article](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html), the [RFC 5322](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322#section-3.4) specification gives an official definition for a valid email address.

Their string, simplified for use in TextWrangler, would be:

Search:

```
([a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*|"(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21\x23-\x5b\x5d-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])*")@((?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?|\[(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]:(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21-\x5a\x53-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])+)\])
```

Replace:

```
\1@\2
```

By itself, it would match:

Timmy Turner <*tturner@example.com*>
"*jamminjeff@example.com*" <*jamminjeff@example.com*>
Susan Alder <*suesblues@example.com*>,
*sallyartist@example.com*

While that DOES match your example email strings, it doesn't give you the exact result you want, since it's also including `"jamminjeff@example.com"`, which should be stripped out.

You can use some filtering before and after it, if you know a few things:

1. Is it okay do discard everything *before* the email string?
2. Is it okay do discard everything *after* the email string?
3. Will any other text be found which butts up against the email string that needs to be removed as well?

If **yes** to 1 and 2, and **no** to 3, prepend that string with `^.*<?\b`, and append it with `\b>?.*$`.

This starts at the beginning of the line, searches for 0 or more characters, an optional opening bracket, and then a word boundary that starts the actual email address.

Then afterward, look for the word boundary on the last character of the email address, an optional closing bracket, and zero or more characters till the end of the line.

Replacing that with `\1@\2` will clean up the entire line to only contain the email address.

Comment: Popped this into BBEdit (on Mac), worked perfectly. 